# Error Code 2318 in Bluestacks

Tags: uninstallation, bluestacks

I am trying to install [bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/es/index.html) on my local machine, however I am getting `error code 2318`.

To fix it, I deleted the folder it installed and then tried to completely uninstall the application. When doing so, I again got this `2318` error code.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

please try again later and delete all the items of bluestack.

and then restart your computer.

then may be it